# Why is my session variable not being maintained between pages?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running Laravel 10. I have a controller method that queries the database and adds the results to a collection, than saves it to the session.

```
public function collection(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->route('id');
   $cards = CardList::where('collectionid', $id)->get();
   $collection = collect();

   foreach($cards as $card)
   {
       $cardArray = [];
       array_push($cardArray,$card->cardid);
       array_push($cardArray,$colors);
       array_push($cardArray,$legalities);
       array_push($cardArray,$imageuris);

       $collection->push($cardArray);
   }
   $request->session()->put('cardCollection', $collection);
   return view('collection');
}
```

I've also tried using Session::put and Session::save().

When it is passed to the collection view, it is displayed fine through the session variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
$collection = session('cardCollection');
foreach($collection as $card)
{
  ?>
    <div>
       <div>
          <a href="<?php echo 'carddetails/'.$card[0]->cardid ?>"</a>
       </div>
       <h3></php echo $card[0]->card_name?></h3>
    </div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

This does display the saved data, and when the link is clicked it goes through this route:

```
Route::get("collection/carddetails/{cardid}", [UserController::class, "displayCard"];
```

But, when I get to the display card function, it doesn't show the saved session data.

```
public function displayCard(Request $request)
{
   $collection = $request->session()->get('cardCollection');
   echo $collection;
}
```

I tried using var_dump with the $collection in displayCard.I also tried different ways of accessing the session variables  and changing the collection to an array, but none of it worked and I just get and empty collection or array,

Comment: Why are these being passed via the session instead of just being passed as parameters to the view?

Comment: You don't need *session_start()* because Laravel don't use the PHP session, it has an custom management. In any case the session is already initialized.

Comment: @ZacharyCraig Because it needs to be passed to a second view

Comment: Note that you are only storing the *id* of *$cards*, I can't understand how you can display *card_name* in the view

Comment: why are you creating a new session?  remove `session_start()` and try again. Are you using blade views?

Comment: @DenisSinyukov I removed it, but the problem persists.

Comment: Are you using `blade` views?

Comment: **1)** Your view accesses some data that is inconsistent with the data stored in the session variable: the code provided is not a valid example.  **2)** in *function displayCard()* you are using an *echo* to display a collection: that can't work, use dump() or dd() instead